# How do I install libmutter-dev?

Tags: apt, elementary, mutter, vala

I am trying to build [gala](https://github.com/elementary/gala), however `make` outputs this error:

```
meson.build:128:4: ERROR:  Problem encountered: No supported mutter library found!
```

I tried installing `libmutter-dev`

```
sudo apt install libmutter-dev
```

But it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libmutter-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libmutter-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I am on elementary OS 5.1.7, which uses Ubuntu 18.04.4 underneath.

How do I install `libmutter-dev`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libmutter-2-dev
```